# Local Authentication on device with Passcode only, not TouchID

Tags: ios, authentication, ios7, xamarin, touch-id

Say my app has sensitive data and I want to ensure the user authenticates locally via Passcode before accessing it.  I'm using the Xamarin TouchID authentication with iOS 8 as seen in this [Xamarin intro to touch ID article](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_touchid/).  I tested this out on an older device that was running iOS 7 and it obviously didn't work.  So my question is, how can I do passcode authentication with iOS 7 devices?  Is this only available with iOS 8?

---

I've noticed the iOS app Mint uses a custom Passcode.  How do you implement a custom passcode that is connected to the "Enter Passcode" button in the TouchID popup?  If I knew how to do that I could implement my own custom passcode so that it works for iOS 7...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Touch ID with iOS 7.

To use a custom passcode just catch the LAErrorUserFallback error in evaluatePolicy.

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                 localizedReason:@"Your Text" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                     if(success) {
                     // handle success
                     } else {
                         NSString *failureReason;
                         switch (error.code) {
                             case LAErrorUserFallback:
                                // show your custom passcode screen
                                 break;
                         } 
                     }
                 }];
```

The code obviously needs to be finished, you need to also handle all the other error cases.

Comment: +1 for including the switch statement on the error.code to handle all the different cases that can occur